# Dropbox V2 API for android has no error code for space full

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Dropbox SDK 1.6.3 (API v1, android) returns an error code 507 If there is no space left on Dropbox

But in Dropbox  SDK 2.0.1 (API v2, android)  Upload API fails with response parsing exception with no clear description that this is because of the space limit. I am unable to locate a corresponding exception.

Does anyone know how to check the error in API v2

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Space-full-message-is-not-returned-by-API/m-p/234938#M12871 ]

Answer (score 0):

v3.0.3 throws UploadErrorException with error reason: insufficient_space

Comment: However the behavior is good only with upload API. If user tries copy API errorcode 500 is returned by server with no message description.